# $location.path() and $routeProvider not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, sockets

I can't redirect to index.html from log.html through $routeProvider and $location.path() and got errors from adding  (controller of log.html run a thousand times), someone can let me know what wrong in here :/

My app structure

```
node_modules
view
-log.html
-index.html
server.js
package.json
```

file log.html as client side

```
 <script type="application/javascript">
     socket = io.connect('http://localhost:1337/');
     angular.module('Log',['ngRoute'])

             .config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider', function($routeProvider,$locationProvider){

                 $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
                 $routeProvider
                         .when('/main', {
                             templateUrl: '/view/index.html'
                         });
                 }])
             .controller('LogCtrl',['$scope','$location', function($scope,$location){

                         console.log('ok baby !!');

                         $scope.addUser = function(){
                             socket.emit('init',$scope.user);
                             $location.path("/main");
                         };

                     }]);


 </script>
<body  >
<div class=" main"  ng-controller = "LogCtrl" style = "width: 300px; ">
<fieldset>
     <form  ng-submit = "addUser()">
         <h2 >Hello!!</h2>
         <input ng-model = "user" required  style = "width: 200px; " placeholder = "Nhập tên của bạn" >
         <input type = "submit" value = "OK">
        <view></view>
    </form>
</fieldset>
</div>
```

and my server side

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
, io = require('socket.io').listen(app)



 , fs = require('fs');        

app.listen(1337);

function handler (req, res) {
  fs.readFile('./view/log.html',
  function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(500,{'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
      return res.end('Error loading log.html');
    }

res.writeHead(200);
res.end(data);
  });
}
```

Comment: What's the error exactly? What do you get in the console?

Comment: It is 'ok baby !!' loop a thousand times

Comment: and although the url is : http://localhost:1337/main the site still is log.html

Comment: It looks like the `handler` function is called many times, sending `log.html` (and its script) to the view repeatedly. Weird, I can't find out why it would do this. Maybe the error is elsewhere.

Comment: Are you sure about the syntax? Aren't you using Express? I checked one of my work files and I got : `app = express(); 
server = require('http').createServer(app); 
io = require('socket.io').listen(server); server.listen(port)`

Comment: i just use socket io for server, let me try using Express but the command of socket io show that it run fine

Comment: Socket.io and Express are not the same thing. Express is just a NodeJS framework to simplify the creation of a server. Socket.io deals with web sockets, it's not a server. While using socket.io depends whether my project needs web sockets, I think Express can always be used, as it just makes things simpler with NodeJs.

Comment: I use expess and it always load index.html through : http://localhost:1337/
`app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/view'));
    app.get('/', function(req, res){
        res.sendfile('log.html');
    });

    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(app.router);`

Comment: Aren't Angular and Node (Express) routes conflicting? I don't really know Angular's routing system yet, but if you set routes in Express (server-side) and also in Angular (client-side), they may conflict. Sorry, I don't know what's going on here.

Comment: Did you fix it? I am facing the same issue :)

Answer (score 0):

What I could do is declare a main state

```
state('main', {
 url : '/',
 templateUrl : '/main.html'
}
```

And you should do the redirect this way

```
$location.path("/");
```